# Replicating rows in a pandas data frame by a column value

Tags: python, pandas

I want to replicate rows in a Pandas Dataframe. Each row should be repeated n times, where n is a field of each row.

```
import pandas as pd

what_i_have = pd.DataFrame(data={
  'id': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
  'n' : [  1,   2,   3],
  'v' : [ 10,  13,   8]
})

what_i_want = pd.DataFrame(data={
  'id': ['A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C'],
  'v' : [ 10,  13,  13,   8,   8,   8]
})
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Is there any reason to do so? I think data duplication is something best avoided.

Comment: Well this is an intermediate step- I am generating the "v" column according to a probability distribution, and then I will add another column by randomly selecting rows from another dataset.

Comment: Still I don't see a reason not to do it directly. But I would need more information on what you are actually trying to achieve.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "do it directly" here? The accepted answer is exactly what I am looking for, though.

Comment: I am using this intermediate step before converting factors to dummy variables.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can use [`Index.repeat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html) to get repeated index values based on the column then select from the DataFrame:

```
df2 = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df.n)]

  id  n   v
0  A  1  10
1  B  2  13
1  B  2  13
2  C  3   8
2  C  3   8
2  C  3   8
```

Or you could use [`np.repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) to get the repeated indices and then use that to index into the frame:

```
df2 = df.loc[np.repeat(df.index.values, df.n)]

  id  n   v
0  A  1  10
1  B  2  13
1  B  2  13
2  C  3   8
2  C  3   8
2  C  3   8
```

After which there's only a bit of cleaning up to do:

```
df2 = df2.drop("n", axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)

  id   v
0  A  10
1  B  13
2  B  13
3  C   8
4  C   8
5  C   8
```

Note that if you might have duplicate indices to worry about, you could use [`.iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) instead:

```
df.iloc[np.repeat(np.arange(len(df)), df["n"])].drop("n", axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)

  id   v
0  A  10
1  B  13
2  B  13
3  C   8
4  C   8
5  C   8
```

which uses the positions, and not the index labels.

Comment: With newer version, can be `df.loc[df.index.repeat(df.n)]`

Comment: @zero: this should be the new accepted answer

Comment: If you get error `ValueError: repeats may not contain negative values.` then try
`df.loc[df.index.repeat(df.n.fillna(value=0))]` (repeat doesn't like nan)

Answer (score 2):

You could use `set_index` and `repeat`

```
In [1057]: df.set_index(['id'])['v'].repeat(df['n']).reset_index()
Out[1057]:
  id   v
0  A  10
1  B  13
2  B  13
3  C   8
4  C   8
5  C   8
```

---

Details

```
In [1058]: df
Out[1058]:
  id  n   v
0  A  1  10
1  B  2  13
2  C  3   8
```

Answer (score 1):

It's something like the `uncount` in `tidyr`:

https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/uncount.html

I wrote a package (https://github.com/pwwang/datar) that implements this API:

```py
from datar import f
from datar.tibble import tribble
from datar.tidyr import uncount

what_i_have = tribble(
    f.id, f.n, f.v,
    'A',  1,   10,
    'B',  2,   13,
    'C',  3,   8
)
what_i_have >> uncount(f.n)
```

Output:

```
  id   v
0  A  10
1  B  13
1  B  13
2  C   8
2  C   8
2  C   8
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the best solution, but I want to share this: you could also use `pandas.reindex()` and `.repeat()`:

```
df.reindex(df.index.repeat(df.n)).drop('n', axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   id   v
0   A   10
1   B   13
1   B   13
2   C   8
2   C   8
2   C   8
```

You can further append `.reset_index(drop=True)` to reset the `.index`.