# Add meaning to values in an object

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, knn

Is it possible to utilize the third column in the following example, to kind of "spread out"/unravel the values in e.g. a *Pandas* *DataFrame* in Python without actually duplicating the rows?
So If we have an object looking like this:

```
X   Y   Count
1   2   3
2   2   2
4   3   1
```

How would I be able to give `Count` meaning here without
unraveling the rows into `Count * row` because that does not seem like a good solution as it makes the data take up much more space in memory.

So I *don't* want the *DataFrame* to just look like this:

```
X   Y   Count
1   2   1
1   2   1
1   2   1
2   2   1
2   2   1
4   3   1
```

Comment: My question actually applies to any programming language

Comment: I don't understand your question.  You say you want to "spread" the values (without saying what that means), then you say you want to "give Count meaning" (without saying what that means), then you say you want to do KNN clustering.  What is it you actually want to do?

Comment: @BrenBarn I find it hard to formulate it. I want the `count` column to have some meaning in doing a KNN clustering or whatever. If the values we're just one entry per row it would be easier, but they are added together based on the *X* and *Y*. Does it make sense?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26777832/replicating-rows-in-a-pandas-data-frame-by-a-column-value

Comment: @ayhan kind of but I would like to avoid duplicating the data if possible as _greole_ is pointing out in the comments

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean something like this:

```
new_df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['Count'])]
```

Then row `df.loc[n]` is repeated `df.Count[n]` number of times. It's sort of a reverse to `groupby`.

**Update**

I tried `new_df['Count'] = 1` and it raised a `SettingWithCopyWarning` unless I made an explicit copy:

```
new_df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['Count'])].copy()
new_df['Count'] = 1    # <- now it works without a warning
```

Comment: Can it be done without duplicating the data like this as it is a very large dataframe?

Comment: You can use `df.loc[...]` without creating a new data frame. But I'm not sure if it duplicates rows or not.

Comment: yes, just do df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['Count'])]  and then df['Count'] = 1