# Repeat Rows in Data Frame n Times

Tags: python, pandas

consider a data frame defined like so:

```
import pandas as pd
test = pd.DataFrame({
    'id' : ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
    'times' : [2, 3, 1, 5]
})
```

Is it possible to create a new data frame from this in which each row is repeated `times` times, such that the result looks like this:

```
>>> result
   id  times
0   a      2
1   a      2
2   b      3
3   b      3
4   b      3
5   c      1
6   d      5
7   d      5
8   d      5
9   d      5
10  d      5
```

Comment: That's fair.  I guess my question is: is this possible?  Currently fumbling through `test.index` and `test.iloc[x]` attempts.

Comment: [I think the answer is yes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26777832/8881141)

Comment: helpful.  thank you.

Comment: @MrT spot on, that is a dupe

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Use a combination of [**`pd.DataFrame.loc`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and [**`pd.Index.repeat`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.repeat.html)

```
test.loc[test.index.repeat(test.times)]

  id  times
0  a      2
0  a      2
1  b      3
1  b      3
1  b      3
2  c      1
3  d      5
3  d      5
3  d      5
3  d      5
3  d      5
```

---

To mimic your exact output, use `reset_index`

```
test.loc[test.index.repeat(test.times)].reset_index(drop=True)

   id  times
0   a      2
1   a      2
2   b      3
3   b      3
4   b      3
5   c      1
6   d      5
7   d      5
8   d      5
9   d      5
10  d      5
```