# How to duplicate rows of a DataFrame based on values of a specific column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following DataFrame `df`:

```
d = {'1': ['25', 'AAA', 2], '2': ['30', 'BBB', 3], '3': ['5', 'CCC', 2], \
     '4': ['300', 'DDD', 2], '5': ['30', 'DDD', 3],  '6': ['100', 'AAA', 3]}

columns=['Price', 'Name', 'Class']

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data=d, orient='index')
df.columns = columns
```

I want to duplicate rows based on values of the column `Class`. In particular, I want to randomly select rows where `Class` is equal to 3, and duplicate them. For example, in current `df` I have 3 rows with `Class` equal to 3. How can I create N duplicates, where N is configurable, for example:

```
N = 2
target_column = "Class"
target_value = 3
new_df = create_duplicates(df, target_column, target_value, N)
```

I was thinking to use for-loop and at each iteration (when `Class` is equal to 3) generate a random number. If it's greater than 0.5, then the row is added to a list of selected rows. This process continues until a list of selected rows contains N rows. Then these N rows are appended to `df`.

Is there a more elegant and shorter way to do the same? Maybe some built-in pandas functions?

Comment: I'm not following your question. Do you want to duplicate the entire dataset by a number `N`? or just some specific classes?

Comment: @QuangHoang: Sorry if it's unclear. I want to duplicate specific rows by a number `N`. The "specific" rows are those ones that have `Class` equal to `3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this script below will do what you need. I lifted the repetition part from: [Repeat Rows in Data Frame n Times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49074021/repeat-rows-in-data-frame-n-times)

```py
n=3
pd.concat([df,df[df['Class']==3].loc[df.index.repeat(n)].dropna()]).sort_values('Name')
```

Comment: Thanks! How does it select rows? Randomly? Or does it take a first row and duplicate it N times?

Comment: In this case it selects the rows with a class = 3. Can you better define what you mean by randomly? You could select one row by index, randomly; you could select N rows by index, but you might end up randomly selecting the same row more than one, so you could put some controls around that; you could randomly select a "class" and duplicate all the rows with the select class.