# Replicating rows in pandas dataframe by column value and add a new column with repetition index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My question is similar to one asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26777832/replicating-rows-in-a-pandas-data-frame-by-a-column-value). I have a dataframe and I want to repeat each row of the dataframe `k` number of times. Along with it, I also want to create a column with values `0` to `k-1`. So

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data={
  'id': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
  'n' : [  1,   2,   3],
  'v' : [ 10,  13,   8]
})

what_i_want = pd.DataFrame(data={
  'id': ['A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C'],
  'n' : [ 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
  'v' : [ 10,  13, 13, 8, 8, 8],
  'repeat_id': [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2]
})
```

Command below does half of the job. I am looking for pandas way of adding the `repeat_id` column.

```
df.loc[df.index.repeat(df.n)]
```

Comment: Your 'half of the job' was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and [`copy`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html) for avoid `SettingWithCopyWarning`:

If you modify values in `df1` later you will find that the modifications do not propagate back to the original data (`df`), and that Pandas does warning.

```
df1 = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df.n)].copy()
df1['repeat_id'] = df1.groupby(level=0).cumcount()
df1 = df1.reset_index(drop=True)
print (df1)
  id  n   v  repeat_id
0  A  1  10          0
1  B  2  13          0
2  B  2  13          1
3  C  3   8          0
4  C  3   8          1
5  C  3   8          2
```

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply! Apparently I can accept an answer only after 10 minutes :D

Comment: @kampta - Really nice question (inut, data, output data, what you try), unfortunately not very often in SO in these days...

Comment: What happens if you don't `copy()`? I'm struggling to see what the issue with doing that is.

Comment: @FHTMitchell - I get `SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy`

Comment: @jezrael Yeah I got that warning too. I continued anyway and nothing happened to `df`. Odd.