# Python, Pandas to calculate average with replicated rows

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

To duplicate the rows according to the value in column 'n', and reassign the value in column 'v' with the average (of v divided by n), like below:

[image]

I am following the sample at [Replicating rows in a pandas data frame by a column value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26777832/replicating-rows-in-a-pandas-data-frame-by-a-column-value).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(data={
'id': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
'n' : [1, 2, 3],
'v' : [ 10, 13, 8]
})
df2 = df.loc[np.repeat(df.index.values,df.n)]

#pd.__version__ 0.20.3
#np.__version__ 1.15.0
```

But it returns me an error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Working Scripts\pv.py", line 14, in <module>
df2 = df.loc[np.repeat(df.index.values, df.n)]
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 445, in repeat
return _wrapfunc(a, 'repeat', repeats, axis=axis)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 61, in _wrapfunc
return _wrapit(obj, method, *args, **kwds)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 41, in _wrapit
result = getattr(asarray(obj), method)(*args, **kwds)
TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('int64') to dtype('int32') according to the rule 'safe'
```

What goes wrong here and how can I correct it? Thank you. (Some others pandas and numpy scripts work all fine in the computer. )

Comment: I can't reproduce, it works on my machine. I have pandas 0.23.4, try upgrading it maybe ?

Comment: It works for me too. Try `df.reindex(df.index.repeat(df.n))`?

Comment: @IMCoins, thank you. I upgraded pandas to 0.23.4 and numpy to 1.15.2 but still the same.

Comment: @Abhi, with upgraded Pandas and Numpy, it's still the same...

Comment: These are litteraly shots in the dark to me since I can't reproduce. Try doing `df.index.values.astype('int32')` ?

Comment: @IMCoins, superb!! the line changes to "df2 = df.loc[np.repeat(df.index.values, df.n.astype('int32'))]", it works. Can you help me with the average question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We usually only answer one question per thread, but you probably didn't know.
For the first question, it has been answered in the comments. Casting to `int32` explicitly solved your problem.

As for the average question, you can always reassign the values doing...

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(data={
'id': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
'n' : [1, 2, 3],
'v' : [ 10, 13, 8]
})
df2 = df.loc[np.repeat(df.index.values,df.n)]
df2.loc[:, 'v'] = df2['v'] / df2['n']

print df2

#   id  n          v
# 0  A  1  10.000000
# 1  B  2   6.500000
# 1  B  2   6.500000
# 2  C  3   2.666667
# 2  C  3   2.666667
# 2  C  3   2.666667
```

I corrected the line `df2['v'] = df2['v'] / df2['n']`, with the `.loc` method which is the best practice when targeting data in pandas.

As stated in the comments, it throws a warning. You can see [reading this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas) that this warning does **false positives**. As long as you know what you are doing, you should be fine. This warning is here to tell you that the method `df.loc[]` returns a copy of the DataFrame, and you are not using it... hence the fact that you might be doing things wrong.

tl;dr from the link, you can disable the warning doing :

`pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None  # default='warn'`

Comment: thanks again. great finding with a perfect solution to the question!

Comment: it also gives little warning on the df2['v'] = df2['v'] / df2['n']. "A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead". What is the way to avoid this warning? thank you.

Comment: it's marvelous!