# Pandas DataFrame copy with condition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-science, data-analysis

I have the following dataframe

[image]

I want to create a new dataframe which will copy each row as per its count variable
which would be like this :

[image: new data frame]

How to calculate arrivaltime during this repetition:
arrival time will be calculated like this:
it will have value of offset if count was 1 and if count was more than 1 it will add interval columns value to offset and it will keep adding interval's value for that repetitive row.

[image]

Help me to achieve this
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replicating rows in a pandas data frame by a column value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26777832/replicating-rows-in-a-pandas-data-frame-by-a-column-value)

Comment: hi @DishinHGoyani, this really solved my problem but I have one more doubt please check edited question, thanks .

Comment: please make it new question it seems different question. No one could answer once it mark as duplicate or until someone undo duplicate.